# Regex: Plus operator does not match. How many times my regex backtrack? [ ^ ]*

Tags: javascript, regex-greedy, regexp-replace

Regex: Plus operator does not match. How many times my regex backtrack? `[ ^ ]*`

```
function stripComments(code) { return code.replace(/\/\/.*|\/\*[^]*\*\//g, ""); }

console.log(stripComments("1 /* a */+/* b */ 1")); // → 1 1

// + operator is missing on the output`
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1: Lazy quantifier

```
\/\/.*|\/\*[^]*?\*\/
```

where `*?` is a [lazy quantifier](https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy) (it consumes as less characters as possible).

Here's how it works on the first matching group:

```
1 /* a */+/* b */ 1
  ^       it matches the first slash
  ^^      it matches the first asterisk
  ^^^     it fails to match the second asterisk and backtracks
  ^^^     it matches the space
  ^^^^    it fails to match the second asterisk and backtracks
  ^^^^    it matches 'a'
  ^^^^^   it fails to match the second asterisk and backtracks
  ^^^^^   it matches the space
  ^^^^^^  it succedes to match the second asterisk
  ^^^^^^^ it matches the second slash
```

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/fhZzB9/1).

#### Solution 2: Greedy quantifier with negative character class

```
\/\/.*|\/\*[^*]*\*\/
```

where `[^*]` is the [negative character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) matching everything but the asterisk.

Here's how it works on the first matching group:

```
1 /* a */+/* b */ 1
  ^       it matches the first slash
  ^^      it matches the first asterisk
  ^^^     it matches the space since it’s not an asterisk
  ^^^^    it matches 'a' since it’s not an asterisk
  ^^^^^   it matches the space since it’s not an asterisk
  ^^^^^^  it fails to match something that is not an asterisk and backtracks
  ^^^^^^  it matches the second asterisk
  ^^^^^^^ it matches the second slash
```

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/iSNu2f/1).

This solution is more efficient but it doesn't work if there are asterisks in the middle.

#### Solution 3: Greedy quantifier with negative character class and alternation

Suppose you have an asterisk in the middle, e.g.:

```
1 /* a*c */+/* b */ 1
```

In this case you can use this regex:

```
\/\/.*|\/\*(?:[^*]|\*(?!\/))*\*\/
```

that in the critical part matches any character that is not an asterisk [OR](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) an asterisk not followed by a slash.

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/LTEGyX/1).

Here's how it works on the first matching group:

```
1 /* a*c */+/* b */ 1
  ^        it matches the first slash
  ^^       it matches the first asterisk
  ^^^      it matches the space since it’s not an asterisk
  ^^^^     it matches 'a' since it’s not an asterisk
  ^^^^^    it fails to match something that is not an asterisk and backtracks
  ^^^^^    it matches the second asterisk
  ^^^^^^   it succeeds to match something that is not a slash
  ^^^^^^   it matches 'c' since it’s not an asterisk
  ^^^^^^^  it matches the third asterisk
  ^^^^^^^^ it matches the second slash
```

---

Which solution to choose depends on your particular case:

- Use solution 1 if you may have many asterisks in the middle.
- Use solution 2 if you cant't have asterisks in the middle.
- Use solution 3 if you may have not so many asterisks in the middle.